# Javascript codes not responding

Tags: javascript

My javascript code is not responding at all. Even simple codes like `alert("Hello World");` both external files and internal scripts, jQuery etc are not all responding

example

````
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/Animate CSS/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/OWL JS/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="animate__animated right-0 wow animate__zoomIn bg-primary"><span class="fa fa-bars"></span> Hello World</h1>
    <div class="wow backInRight">
        Content to Reveal Here
    </div>
    <noscript>Hello</noscript>
    <script>
        new WOW().init();
        alert("Hello word");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            alert("Hello" + i);
        }
    </script>
    <script src="./assets/JQuery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/Popper JS/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/Wow JS/wow.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/OWL JS/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>```
````

Comment: `new WOW().init();` <-- You call this before you even load the library. It is like yelling for a person by name before they walk into the room. They have no clue you are there. The error in your console tells you this.

Comment: Tried that still no response. The problem is that not js code work. When I write scripts in my console window, it works. But in my code, it doesn't.

Comment: As @epascarello said console tells you everything.

Comment: _Uncaught ReferenceError: WOW is not defined
    at index.html:22
wow.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '*'_ This what I get in the console

Comment: And that is telling you WOW is not there. You are loading the script after you use it. You need to move your code that uses WOW to the bottom. It libraries need to load first.

Comment: Make sure `<script src="./assets/Wow JS/wow.js"></script>` is placed before you use `WOW`.

Comment: That doesn't explain why simple codes like ```alert("Hello World");``` don't run.